PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: EOF marker not found after converting ppt file to pdf using libreoffice
Hi folks i have converted a ppt file to pdf using ,
/usr/bin/libreoffice--headless --convert-to pdf
after convertion i am getting the error
"PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: EOF marker not found"
while reading file using python library PyPDF2 and also not able to open the converted pdf in adobe .

PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf
